# Who had the Holy Spirit from birth?

Tags: jesus, pneumatology, john-the-baptist

John was filled with the Holy Spirit in the womb and Jesus was conceived by the Holy Spirit. Is there anyone else in the bible that had the Holy Spirit from birth, Samson or Elijah?

> For he will be great in the sight of the Lord; and he will drink no
> wine or liquor, ***and he will be filled with the Holy Spirit while
> yet in his mother’s womb***. (NASB) Luke 1:15

> Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother
> Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found
> with child of the Holy Spirit. Then Joseph her husband, being a just
> man, and not willing to make her a public example, was minded to put
> her away privily. But while he thought on these things, behold, the
> angel of the Lord appeared unto him in a dream, saying, Joseph, thou
> son of David, fear not to take unto thee Mary thy wife: ***for that
> which is conceived in her is of the Holy Spirit***. Matthew 1:18-20
> (NASB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest I can find is the case of Samson about whom it is recorded:

- Judges 13:7 - But he said to me, ‘Behold, you will conceive and give birth to a son. Now, therefore, do not drink wine or strong drink, and do not eat anything unclean, because the boy will be a Nazirite to God from the womb until the day of his death.’ ”  See also V5.
- Judges 16:17 - Samson told her all that was in his heart: “My hair has never been cut, because I have been a Nazirite to God from my mother’s womb. If I am shaved, my strength will leave me, and I will become as weak as any other man.”

It is possible that David had a similar experience:

- Ps 22:10 - From birth I was cast upon You; from my mother’s womb You have been my God.  See also Ps 71:6.

There is a similar comment about Isaiah -

- Isa 49:1 - Listen to Me, O islands; pay attention, O distant peoples: The LORD called Me from the womb; from the body of My mother He named Me.

Jeremiah has another similar statement -

- Jer 1:5 - “Before I formed you in the womb I knew you, and before you were born I set you apart and appointed you as a prophet to the nations.”

Since prophets can only prophesy by means of the inspiration of the Holy Spirit (2 Tim 3:16, 2 Peter 1:20, 21), these prophets were given (according to the text) at birth.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything that say anything about Elijah birth or mentioning it, he is first introduced as a grown man in 1 Kings 17:1.

Neither does anything state that Samson had the Holy Spirit from birth but rather that he was dedicated with a Nazarite vow from the womb just like John the Baptist was.

> 4 Now therefore, be careful not to drink wine or strong drink, nor eat
> any unclean thing. 5 For behold, you shall conceive and give birth to
> a son, and no razor shall come upon his head, ***for the boy shall be
> a Nazirite to God from the womb***; and he shall begin to deliver
> Israel from the hands of the Philistines.” (Judges 13:4-5)
>
> 7 But he said to me, ‘Behold, you shall conceive and give birth to a
> son, and now you shall not drink wine or strong drink nor eat any
> unclean thing, ***for the boy shall be a Nazirite to God from the womb
> to the day of his death***.’” (Judges 13:7)

> 15 For he will be great in the sight of the Lord; ***and he will drink no
> wine or liquor, and he will be filled with the Holy Spirit while still
> in his mother’s womb***. (Luke 1:15)

A Nazarite vow from the womb = filled with the Holy Spirit it does not say but we know Samson had the Holy Spirit when he fought.

5 Then Samson went down to Timnah with his father and mother, and came as far as the vineyards of Timnah; and behold, a young lion came roaring toward him. 6 ***The Spirit of the Lord came upon him mightily***, so that he tore him as one tears a young goat though he had nothing in his hand; but he did not tell his father or mother what he had done. (Judges 14:5-6)

19 ***Then the Spirit of the Lord came upon him mightily***, and he went down to Ashkelon and killed thirty of them and took their spoil and gave the changes of clothes to those who told the riddle. And his anger burned, and he went up to his father’s house. (Judges 14:19)

**BUT** also the spirit cam upon Othniel, Gideon & Jepthat;
The Spirit of the Lord came upon him [***Othniel the son of Kenaz***], and he judged Israel Jdg 3:10. So the Spirit of the Lord came upon ***Gideon*** .. Jdg 6:34. Now the Spirit of the Lord came upon ***Jephthah*** ... Jdg 11:29